# Rails - Return Rendered Partial in AJAX response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller

I'm trying to return a partial as a response for an AJAX request on rails. Yet it refuses to return the rendered partial and I get:

```
expected to find text "Your query returned no results." in "#"
```

model_controller.rb

```
class ModelController < ApplicationController
  before_filter: require_xhr
  def index
    # do stuff
    @yada = yada
    render partial: 'index'
  end
  private
    def require_xhr
       if !request.xhr?
         redirect_to 'example.com'
       end
     end
 end
```

note that `puts render partial: 'index'` yields the exact content I want.

Maybe it's because I'm new to Rails, but it seems like it tries to do way too much for you and important things get obscured to the background. I just want to render a block of content and render it as a string. I feel like this is way easier in Node, Django, and Java.

Comment: is 'index' partial (_index.html.erb) or it's just view file - index.html.erb? if it's view file you can render it without layout (by itself) replace render partial: 'index'   to   render layout: false

Comment: Thanks Alex. Didn't work though. I've tried it both ways. as a partial with `_index.html.haml`, as render 'model/index' with `index.html.haml`, and render layout: false with `index.html.haml`. ALl the same result. Why will it `put` the result I want but not return it in a response??? The only thing I can conclude so far is that I really don't like Rails.

Comment: nm I'm an idiot. The problem was with my test. I had `expect(response).to have_text('Your query returned no results.')` instead of `expect(response.body).to have_text('Your query returned no results.')`

Comment: good luck with Rails, Eric :)

Comment: Also, on an unrelated note..Welcome to Rails first of all but also, it's good practice to make your controllers plural.. like `ModelsController` :) Good luck with Rails!